# Windows Server 2008 r2 Windows Update

Tags: active-directory, windows-update

I have a problem,

I have recently decided to install Active Domain Directory Service on my Win 2008 r2 server. It was all well and good until I downloaded the latest windows updates from Microsoft (auto is off). reboot and crash boom bang, it just hung at the loading windows screen. Wasn't able to recover it so after a format and installing all the updates first (and creating a backup image this time) I installed AD DS. Same thing happens. Restored from image and tried again, same result.

Now I'm guessing there is some kind of incompatibility, but where, and how do I fix it, short of another format and no windows updates

Answer (score 0):

If it happens again, force it off, then put the system drive in another machine.

Then look at %system root$\WindowsUpdate.log to see if you get any clues.